# Unable to install R packages

Tags: r, dropbox

Most times when I attempt to install an R package, I'll get the following error message. The error message I got below occurred when I tried to install a package named "moments". The package was found, downloaded and unpacked but I don't understand why it couldn't be installed. The destination folder does exist. It is not my R working directory though, if that matters.

```
package ‘moments’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to move temporary installation ‘C:\Users\fs103799\Dropbox\R3.3.1\library\file1da0c1d9622a1\moments’ to ‘C:\Users\fs103799\Dropbox\R3.3.1\library\moments’

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\fs103799\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp6ZSV46\downloaded_packages
```

Comment: I assume you've checked for valid permissions and confirmed there is enough hard drive space available? (I also assume that Dropbox doesn't prevent you writing to the Dropbox folder if you don't have enough space available on Dropbox?)

Comment: Looks like a file permissions issue.

Comment: Try manually deleting it in your filesystem. In Windows you may need to use the "as Administrator" option.

Comment: I am getting the same issue when installing into Dropbox folder while Dropbox is running, exit Dropbox then try to install, it should work. I have admin rights on the computer. R 3.3.0. Windows 7. Could you add the command you are running to install the packages.

Comment: Oh yea, I didn't notice you're installing into dropbox. The RStudio guys say you shouldn't use Dropbox with anything to do with R (sometimes I break this advice, but it can cause various problems).

Comment: @Hack-R - I'm not sure why it's trying to install this into Dropbox. That is not my current working directory, which I determine by calling getwd().

Comment: Installations don't happen in your working directory. They happen in your library and your temp file directories.  You can change those. `.libPaths( c( .libPaths(), "~/userLibrary") )`

Comment: @Hack-R - Ok. I installed R into a DropBox folder. I guess that was a mistake. I will resintall in a non-Dropbox location.

Comment: @zx8754 - Your suggestion worked. I closed Dropbox and the R installation worked. If you create this as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @RandyMinder Yea, definitely definitely don't install R in Dropbox

Comment: @Hack-R - Closing Dropbox allowed me to install the package successfully. So I guess I'll have to do this each time I want to install a package, which won't be that often.

Comment: @RandyMinder Yea, but Dropbox can also corrupt your other R files if you're changing them when it's syncing. If you're going to risk it then you can use Select Sync to tell Dropbox to ignore critical files and folders like R project files. I have to say, if you don't install packages often you're a very atypical R user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am getting the same issue when installing into Dropbox folder while Dropbox is running, exit Dropbox then try to install, it should work.

```
install.packages("moments", lib = "C:/xxx/Dropbox/")
```

I have admin rights on the computer.

```
R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 7 x64 (build 7601) Service Pack 1
```